# How do people handle the "recent app" arrow in iOS using React Native?

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm developing a React Native app w/ `react-navigation` control.

As you can see iOS' "recent app" return arrow (is that the actual name?) overlays the back arrow that's part of the normal navigation.  Example:

[image]

How are people handling this?  Is there a way to disable it?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there is no way to change it even iOS native development because this is a feature built into iOS. And it is called `Back to App`, `Return To Previous App` or `Previous App` button. But the names are not official.

You would change your header bar's layout.

Comment: That's a bummer.  Is there any way to detect if it's present, and possibly dimensions?  Or are people just avoiding back buttons now?